# Guardian and Sessions in Phoenix app

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm using Guardian on a phoenix app but I can't use the put_session and get_session methods in controllers with Guardian

```
defmodule Bonsai.LedgerController do
 use Bonsai.Web, :controller

 alias Bonsai.{Repo, Ledger}

 plug Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated, handler: Bonsai.SessionController
 plug :scrub_params, "ledger" when action in [:create]

 def index(conn, _params) do
   put_session(conn, :sess_val, "A value") # Generates error
   ledgers = Repo.all(Ledger)

   render(conn, "index.json", ledgers: ledgers)
 end
```

end

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: when trying conn = put_session(conn, :my_key, "A value")
[error] #PID<0.638.0> running Bonsai.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /api/v1/ledgers
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (ArgumentError) session not fetched, call fetch_session/2

Comment: Do you have `plug :fetch_session` in your Router pipeline?

Comment: Added, now it doesn't raise any errors but it's not storing data on the session when I try to recover what with get_session(conn, :my_token) for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First of all, you need to fetch the session in your pipeline. This is commonly done in your router:

```
pipeline :browser do
  #...
  plug :fetch_session
  #...
end
```

The second issue is that you are calling `put_session` however the result is not being used. Try this:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  conn = put_session(conn, :sess_val, "A value")
  ledgers = Repo.all(Ledger)

  render(conn, "index.json", ledgers: ledgers)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that fixed, I'm really having issues with my editor, now I'm using vimi but when using atom I have to restart the server in order that changes take effect.